# How to set PT_DENY_ATTACH in Xamarin.iOS?

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

We recently had a pen tester audit our app and one of the findings was that a person with a jailbroken device can attach a local debugger.

The solution they suggested was to enable `PT_DENY_ATTACH` when starting up the app. This is fairly easy to do in a native app but I haven't been able to figure it out with our Xamarin app (not forms).

I've tried creating an objc framework in Xcode, binding that and pulling it in. I've also tried to create a shared c++ library but that isn't possible in VS Mac.

I know that `PT_DENY_ATTACH` has been circumvented but I'd still like to know how to implement it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that my objc framework was behaving properly just not in the way I expected. For some reason I was still able to attach the Visual Studio debugger but when I move to Xcode and try to attach its debugger it fails when the framework is called.

To answer my question:

In Xcode I created a new static library with one class:

`GDBManager.h`

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface GDBManager : NSObject
+(void)DisableGDB;
@end
```

`GDBManager.m`

```
#import "GDBManager.h"
#import <dlfcn.h>
#import <sys/types.h>

@implementation GDBManager
typedef int (*ptrace_ptr_t)(int _request, pid_t _pid, caddr_t _addr, int _data);
#define PT_DENY_ATTACH 31

+(void)DisableGDB {
    void* handle = dlopen(0, RTLD_GLOBAL | RTLD_NOW);
    ptrace_ptr_t ptrace_ptr = dlsym(handle, "ptrace");
    ptrace_ptr(PT_DENY_ATTACH, 0, 0, 0);
    dlclose(handle);
}
@end
```

I followed these instructions to create a fat file for my library and to use that in a binding project.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/binding-objective-c/walkthrough

I then add the generated dll to my Xamarin.iOS project and call it above `UIApplication.Main(args, null, "AppDelegate");` in `Main.cs`